# How does MongoDB cursor behave when the collection is being changed?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, document-database

Suppose I'm using the cursor to iterate a subset of the documents, ordered by some field let's say.

What happens if while iterating, a new document is being inserted or a current one is being deleted?

Would that affect the cursor or does it MongoDB make some sort of snapshot of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in a transaction with [read concern snapshot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-snapshot/), you are reading from a consistent snapshot of the data.

Otherwise you could be experiencing various phenomena [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Read_phenomena).